# fluent-ffmpeg in Node.js adds 50 ms of silence to the beginning of the file

Tags: node.js, ffmpeg

Did anyone else encounter this issue? I'm using the library to generate extremely precise stimuli for psycho-acoustic experiments, and I just noticed that the audio files I output using the library  have 50 msec of silence in the beginning of them.

All my code does is concatenate existing files.
None of the existing files have silence in their beginnings or ends.

Any idea how to solve this?

Comment: Did you manage to fix this?

Comment: ...ish. mp3 adds the silence, but when exporting .wav it works correctly, so I just gave up the mp3

Comment: Yes, I observed a similar pattern. Thanks anyway!